# Get drawable from pdf

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have PDF images from some project for iOS and all images in .pdf. How I can use this pdf images in android as I've used png files (for background, for example)?

Comment: you can convert files from [PDF to PNG](https://pdf2png.com/) and then add them to Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PDF as drawables or graphical assets, only png or jpeg.

A best practise, as a developer, is to use assets created by designers with Adobe Illustrator, Sketch, etc.